# printing a square with diagonals

Tags: c

I want to print this if the user typed in for example 2:

```
+---+ 
|\ /|
| X |
|/ \|
+---+
```

It's a square with a size of 2n+1 for each side of it if n is the number that is being typed in by the user

I'm not allowed to use arrays or other functions for the diff coords.

So I managed to print the first row of it like so:

```
for (int i = 0;i < ((size * 2) + 1);i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ((size * 2) + 1);j++){
        if (i == 0 && (j == 0 || j == size * 2)){
            printf("+");
        }
        else if (i == 0 && j != i){
            printf("-");
        }

        if (i > 0 && (j == 0 || j == size * 2)){
            printf("|");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

which prints out

```
+---+
||
||
||
||
```

How can i deal with spaces and the rest of the diagonals?

Comment: I suggest you to think about a single "cell" with coordinates `x` and `y` and think of a function `symbol(x,y)` which will return the symbol corresponding to these coordinates.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i can't create more functions, this is already in a function

Comment: I suggest breaking the problem down. Try creating an empty frame first, then worry about adding the cross lines later.

Comment: Do you mean you can't create more functions because of assignment requirements? You can create a new function and call it from this one...

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline assignment requirements

Comment: Still do it. You can refactor it afterwards and inline it back. This way it is easier to think about the problem (and, well. It's a stupid restriction if you ask me).

Comment: Your code doesn't match the output shown in the question. When I wrap it in a `main` function and run it I get `+---+||||||||` in one line. Please [edit] your question and show enough code to allow compiling and testing it. You can omit the user input and use hard coded values like `int size = 2;`

Comment: @Bodo yeah sorry, i didn't copy the last condition that added the first part of the diagonal

Comment: You managed to put one column and one row correctly........which means you solved the whole problem!   Ask your self this question: what i need to change in the code of row one in order to put row two? Same for the columns.

Comment: @Abdirahman it's a bit more complicated than that unfortunately. i need a way to track the indices of i,j and decided where to print each char

Comment: @DarkLeader Your code also doesn't print a newline. instead of removing the `\` from the output, better add the code that prints it. Instead of using e.g. `printf("+");` I suggest to initialize a variable for the character, e.g. `char ch = ' ';` and modify it e.g. `ch = '+';` and at the end of the conditions print it with `printf("%c", ch);`

Comment: @bodo again, i print the newline after each iteration of the first loop, so at the beggining i = 0 and after the second loop finishes then i printf("\n") i just didn't add it here because i already figured that one out

Comment: @DarkLeader Instead of explaining the code in comments, [edit] the question and make sure that the code can be compiled and run and that it matches the output. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think like this. You only have to worry about the first half plus the middle. This is because the second half is the same as the first but reversed.

Then you figure out a formula for how a specific row should look like, only by which row it is and total number of rows.

The first row is easy. It's a `+`, 2n-1 `-` and another `+`.

Then each row except the middle one will be two `|`, with a `\` and a `/` and a total of 2n-3 spaces. If y is the row and the second row is indexed 0, then (2n-3)-2y spaces in the middle and y spaces outside the middle.

Lastly, we have the middle row that is two `|`, n-1 spaces, `X`, n-1 spaces, `|`.

Putting it all together:

```
// First row
putchar('+');
for(int i=0; i<2*n-1; i++)
        putchar('-');
putchar('+');
putchar('\n');

// Those between
for(int y=0; y<n-1; y++) {
    putchar('|');
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        putchar(' ');
    putchar('\\');
    for(int i=0; i<(2*n-3)-2*y; i++)
        putchar(' ');
    putchar('/');
    for(int i=0; i<y; i++)
        putchar(' ');
    putchar('|');
    putchar('\n');
}

// Middle row
putchar('|');
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    putchar(' ');
putchar('X');
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    putchar(' ');
putchar('|');
putchar('\n');
```

This prints correctly to the middle row. In order to print the rest, just copy the "Those between" for loop, but change to `for(int y=n-2; y>0; y--)` and switch places on `\` and `/`. Lastly, just copy the code for the first row.

Comment: Nice explanation, but I wish you hadn't written the code.  New learners need to learn by doing!

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm always hesitating about that, but my view is that either the answer should contain code or else the question should be deleted.

Comment: My opinion (which may be in the minority) is that SO can get too fixated on code; there can be fine questions -- and fine answers -- without it.

Comment: @SteveSummit Ok, true. I was a bit unclear. But code is never wrong. I see your point though.

Comment: What @SteveSummit said. You really shouldn't have spelled it out for OP :-(

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a bit on @EugeneSh.'s idea: Think of it this way. You have two loops in which you're iterating over (2n+1) x (2n+1) characters in the output. Each of these has to be one of the following: `+`, `-`, `|`, `\`, `/`, `X` or it has to have a   (a space character).

You can't avoid printing all those (2n+1)^2 characters. So - don't try to. Just decide, for each of them, which one it needs to be. Form the appropriate conditions and check for them. You've already done it for 3 of the possible characters - just do the rest.

The "trick" is that if none of the conditions for the non-space characters is satisfied - you print a space ().

PS - You might want to consider the `switch() { ... }` statement for doing this, with `default:` used for printing the space.

Answer (score 0):

Homework is an exploration.

You are trying to print an object that will have a number of decisions.  You need to code for each one.  Simple code for this might try the approach of 'print all the characters in a square, deciding what each should be.'  That's your approach 
so far.   Next you need to write if statements and correctly answer do I print '+', '-', '|', '\', '/', 'X', or ' '?

You need to think about each character in order.  For example, your first test, `if (i == 0 && (j == 0 || j == size * 2))`, but you need to expand it to get the '+' on the last line as well.

One base idea is to first get something working.  I suggest you start with your code and add items as you go.  Here is an outline with '+' working:

```
for (int i = 0;i < ((size * 2) + 1);i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ((size * 2) + 1);j++){
        if ((i == 0 || i == size * 2) && (j == 0 || j == size * 2)){
            printf("+");
        }
        // more else if for '-', etc.
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have it printing the '+' at the four corners of a square, add the logic for each other charcter, checking that you get a square with the '-', '_', etc., correct.

One other point is that there are other ways to do the problem, and you should explore how some seem less error prone than others.  For example, if you change your outline to:

```
int last = size * 2
for (int i = 0; i < last + 1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < last + 1; j++){
        if ((i == 0 || i == last) && (j == 0 || j == last) {
           ...
```

you may find that eliminating repetition and parenthesis makes it less error prone.  Notice or keep track of the errors you make.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of your program that prints spaces where you don't specify anything else.

You can use it as a starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size = 2;
    int i, j;
    char ch;

    for (int i = 0;i < ((size * 2) + 1);i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ((size * 2) + 1);j++){
            ch = ' ';
            if (i == 0 && (j == 0 || j == size * 2)){
                ch = '+';
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j != i){
                ch = '-';
            }

            if (i > 0 && (j == 0 || j == size * 2)){
                ch = '|';
            }
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
+---+
|   |
|   |
|   |
|   |
```